# Changing motherboards, avoiding bluescreens - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, pata, device-manager

When I used to have Windows XP and upgraded the computer, I got bluescreens at boot, usually due to a changed IDE controller. How do I avoid this? I am now upgrading windows 7 to windows 7 changing the motherboard. I want to avoid bluescreens and failed boots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your hard drive and do a clean install.  Operating systems aren't really designed to deal with upgrading a motherboard.  Sysprep is the only way I'd consider doing it, but you could try booting into safe mode and uninstalling all devices present in Device Manager.  I don't believe you can change between different HAL kernels or bootloaders, though, so if you're going from IDE to AHCI or from BIOS to UEFI you have to clean install.

Comment: Just did a reinstall. Luckily all I need to do is: 1) Copy over the program's Users\ Profile Settings 2) Run the program's installer. Usually that's enough to get back most of the settings.

Comment: -1 For the format the hard drive. All versions of Windows, post 2000 support some type of repair mode installation. That does not wipe out files.

Comment: I find repair installs have problems which clean installs never suffer from and occasionally don't fix anything at all because of what the system tries to reuse, therefore I never recommend them.  I did not say "delete your data".  I assumed you'd already have backed that up when you decided to upgrade the motherboard.

Comment: That's probably why Windows 7 does not support repair installs in the traditional sense. But 7 does allow to reinstall over an existing installation, preserving the filesystem.